# Reverse polarity protection with two-cell series Li-ion

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-protection, reverse-polarity

I plan on using a P-channel MOSFET for reverse polarity protection. The MOSFET I chose is the [SISS27DN-T1-GE3](https://www.vishay.com/docs/62847/siss27dn.pdf) - it has a 30 V V<sub>DS</sub>, ~5.5 mΩ R<sub>DS</sub>, and +/-20 V V<sub>GS</sub>.

Since this MOSFET has a higher V<sub>DS</sub> and V<sub>GS</sub> voltage than expected from two Li-ions, I believe I can forgo the zener diode and resistor to clamp voltage to the gate.

Any gotchas I didn't think of? I do have a charging/balancing circuit for the 2 batteries  - will this negatively affect the circuit?

[image: 2 cell RPP circuit]

Comment: Is the battery connected to GND? What is SUPPLY_MID signal?

Comment: Yes - the 4 connectors are terminal clips (+ and - for each battery). So CN1 is the negative side of of the series and CN4 is the positive side. SUPPLY_MID is for the battery charge/balance circuit.

Comment: So far so good, under given condition seems Ok. You could provide a bit more of the schematic for a final judgement. It would not overwhelm us :)